# Reserved Instance and AWS Marketplace AMI with Software License

Tags: amazon-ec2, reserved-instances

How does billing work when purchasing a RI and launching an instance that runs a marketplace software that also charges for a software license (say the Cisco CSR1000v, $0.622/hr as of today)? Is the license cost per year added on top of the RI price?

Thank you.

Comment: Any queries regarding the answer? please feel free to accept it if you are happy. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an AWS perspective the software charge and the underlying EC2 instance charge are separate.  You can see in this image below the $0.622/hr charge is the software charge when running on a T2 Medium instance, but that the instance charge is a separate column $0.046 which is the On Demand pricing for the US East N. Virginia region.

When you purchase an RI for (in this example) a T2 Medium, AWS automatically discounts based on the inventory that matches.  So if you had started the Cisco Marketplace item running on a T2 Medium and had purchased a T2 Medium RI that was not matched to any other existing instance, then you would see a discount for the compute automatically.

More details: [How Reserved Instances Are Applied](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/apply_ri.html)

[image: Cisco CSR 1000V pricing]